# Receiving bad Contextname (crashing my app) only when user is from Google review team

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have created an action currently under review for approval and there is a problem (better described below) that shows only when the user is a member of the Google review team. 
5 coworkers/friends of mine from different countries (India, Germany, Switzerland, Italy) have tested the app from android Google assistant and action console simulator and the problem never occurred. The application worked flawlessly.

I hope someone can explain why this happen and suggest a solution. I worked hard on this app and I cannot publish it and have real users until this problem is not solved.

TECHNICAL DETAILS ON THE PROBLEM:
basically the Context name received from the Google team tester is crashing the Google cloud api Parser. I am using C# in my web hook with Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2 1.0.0-beta02.

Example of Context name received when tester from google action team uses the application
projects/blitzy-84d12/agent/environments/__aog-2/users/-/sessions/ABwppHEMNPVl9O-OVXEOzT_ch6uSa_cZ08pHV6YUF5kpkSwZHDVmk6ShexlLi50yWFMkktYClMDX01z9/contexts/sendmessageprocessing

Example of Context name recevied when me or my friends test the application (using android phone or action console simulator) 
projects/voice-rider/agent/sessions/ABwppHFyb9HLDSmiETz6d91QveUw0kTIjC5T1kJmNF2QVKrRBrHtTvR3t83lhU9hVxORZ8rXBbQBtRQ/contexts/tellmemypositionprocessing

Error produced while parsing the context name with Google.Cloud.Dialogflow.V2.ContextName.Parse(String contextName)
errMsg=Name does not match template: incorrect number of segments

the source code of the error can be seen at line 272 of this github source:
https://github.com/googleapis/gax-dotnet/blob/master/Google.Api.Gax/PathTemplate.cs

it's quite easy to understand why the Google cloud api Parser throw the exception, it is receiving a context name with more segments than expected. By segments we mean the number of strings separated by a slash '/' character. Displaying the context name of my tests with the one of google team tester we can see the difference:

projects/blitzy-84d12/agent/environments/__aog-2/users/-/sessions/ABwppHEMNPVl9O-OVXEOzT_ch6uSa_cZ08pHV6YUF5kpkSwZHDVmk6ShexlLi50yWFMkktYClMDX01z9/contexts/sendmessageprocessing

projects/voice-rider/agent/                              sessions/ABwppHFyb9HLDSmiETz6d91QveUw0kTIjC5T1kJmNF2QVKrRBrHtTvR3t83lhU9hVxORZ8rXBbQBtRQ/contexts/tellmemypositionprocessing

in the google team tester contextname there is this additional block:
environments/__aog-2/users/-/

composed of 4 additional "alien" segments that crash the Google api parser

I could try to override the Google api parser with my own parser but really I dont want to enter that path, for the negative side effects and future compatibility it could produce.

Thank you for your support

Comment: The environments where added only [recently](https://dialogflow.com/docs/agents/versions-environments) and are still in beta, so it seems that your parser was not updated yet.

Comment: thanks @gmolau.I am using the latest Google API parser. I can imagine it's a little diff between parser/contextnames, probably these Google testers have a very new version of software generating fields my parser doesn't understand. However it works with standard software on android google assitant on phones or action simulator. The testers should use standard software IMO not versions too ahead of the market. Anyway I am implementing right now a workaround that seem to fix, it's stripping away this new information my parser does not understand. I will update this thread as i progress.